# Data manager を使ってshift jisで保管されたDB2でから日本語を正しく取得するには？

Tags: database, jdbc

Data managerを使って、Shift-JISで保管されているDBから値を取得したいです。

Data managerから日本語の入ったデータを取得すると、文字化けしてしまっています。
どうしたらきちんと表示されるでしょうか？

Comment: Jdbc接続時の文字列に、エンコード指定が入れられれば、この問題は解決すると見ています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

調べたところによると、JDBCはエンコードが指定できず、UTF-8で接続するため、このような現象が発生してしまうようです。

代わりに、ODBC接続をすることで文字化けしないようにできそうでしたが、java8からはodbcjdbcドライバが削除されてしまい、利用できません。

Java7以前を用いて、odbcから接続をすれば、文字化けしなくなるかもしれませんが、試してはいません。